# PHP - Is It possible to return 2 new Class Object

Tags: php, laravel

is there any possible to return a function in a multiple add new Class Object ?
THanks in advance.

example :

```
public function model()
{
  return new Users(['...' => user1, .....]);
  return new Customers(['...' => customer1, .....]);
}
```

Comment: you can return Pair

Answer (score 0):

You can put them in an array and return both. You can then access the object you want and process it further.

Answer (score 0):

Once the function reaches the `return` statement lines/codes below, that won't get executed. If you use an *Advanced IDE* (PhpStorm which I use) it will show you a message saying "Unreachable...".

[image: error]

---

To archive your goal, you can pass them in an array.

```
public function model()
{
    return [
        'user' => new User(....),
        'customer' => new Customers(...)
    ];
}
```